# Multiple Passive connections to vsftpd server

Tags: c, freebsd, vsftpd

I am trying to upload multiple files simultaneously. after establishing a data connection in passive mode, my client sending another "pasv" request to the vsftp server to get server and port value. so that i can connect to the vsftpd using the new set of port and ip values. but server(vsftpd) is not responding for this second pasv command.

here is the sequence of commands my client is sending after login.

PASV                 ------> to server

227 entering passive
 mode (x,x,x,x,d,d)   <------ from server

STOR xyz.txt        -------> to server

150 OK to send data  <------- from server

...... creating socket and connecting to the server using x,x,x,x,d.d.

After that again i am sending pasv to get another port for second connection 
PASV                -------> to server

But server is not sending anything back.

can anyone help on this issue.

thanks
-Alexander

Answer (score 1):

You can only have one pair of command connection,data connection to an FTP server. That is, you cannot set up a 2 data connections to an FTP server by issuing the PASV command twice. 
You'll have to set up another FTP command connection if you want to do another data connection as well.

Comment: Hey Thanks .. but is it with VSFTPD only or it is Standard?